# What's the best method for ignoring the BBCode between <code> tags in a full-post BBCode parser?

Tags: html, forum

To clarify on the title a bit more, this is for a plugin for my forum.

I'm doing this:

```
div.html( parser( div.html() ) )
```

When sending the html string to the parser, of course I get something like:

```
"[BBC][/BBC]\n<code>[BBC][/BBC]</code>"
```

What's the best method I could use to prevent the parsing of the BBC tag inside the code tag?

Comment: Very hacky way: replace `[` inside the `code` element with `[[B][/B]` to prevent them from being parsed.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid text-direct methods as they can easily be borked by the user... a DOM method would be much better if easily (low performance use) possible

Comment: What does your parser look like as it stands?

Comment: Right now it just attempts to undo the work that was done and in some cases replace things like '[' with the HTML escape sequence (doesn't work well, and is easy to break).

Comment: I don't understand what is being asked here at all. Your code blocks make even less sense.

Comment: what I'm asking is for a method to skip over <code></code>

Answer (score 2):

A workaround would be to save each code block before the plugin parses the post, then restore the blocks afterwards.

EDIT:
So I've changed things around and am working on a slightly more efficient method rather than text replacement (mentioned in the OP), which will still be considered here.

Here's what I'm using now:

```
function parse( node ) {

    // backup code blocks
    var codes = []; node.find('code').each(function() { codes.push($(this).html()); });

    // Do whatever you need to here

    // restore the code blocks
    var i=0; node.find('code').each(function() { $(this).html(codes[i]); i = i+1; });

};
```

^ applies the changes to the element directly

For the old method mentioned in the OP:

```
function parse( post ) {
    var node = $('<div>'+post+'</div>');

    // backup the code blocks
    var codes = []; node.find('code').each(function() { codes.push($(this).html()); });

    post = ''; // <-- Do whatever you need to here

    node.html( post ); // update the node

    // restore the code blocks
    var i=0; node.find('code').each(function() { $(this).html(codes[i]); i = i+1; });

    return node.html();
};
```

I don't recommend this method, it's just a workaround until I'm able to just ignore code blocks altogether.

Comment: edited using .find() as it searches recursively, unlike .children()

Comment: edited, removed "var blocks" as restoration didn't always update the node.